# Why does this C computation involving exponents produce the wrong answer?

Tags: c, math

I am trying to implement the below formula on C

[image]

Here is my code:

```
int function(int x){
   return pow(10, (((x-1)/(253/3))-1));
}

int main(void){
  int z = function(252);
  printf("z: %d\n",z); 
  return 0;
}
```

it outputs **10**. However a calculator outputs **94.6**.

could anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: (((252-1)/(253/3))-1) == ((251/84)-1) == (2-1) == 1. 10^1 == 10. Good old integer division.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question was pretty straightforward.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy "questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved". And they "must show some research effort" too. Any reasonably good beginner C language guide mentions integer division.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy Also: upvotes are not for "correcting" downvotes.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'd rather believe that he simply didn't notice it. We're not robots.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy Possible.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy - while sometimes I find H2CO3 to be.. somewhat harsh, in this case I agree with him. We may not be robots, but we are capable of using debuggers and breaking down problems. Expanding the code of `function()` the way I did in the comments and following along with a calculator would have shown that when dividing `int`s the values were not as expected; that would then lead to the answer that `int` division is to blame

Comment: It's a total stretch that this question is a duplicate. Don't get me wrong, I still think it should be closed for showing lack of effort, but so does the duplicate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that in this line

```
(((x-1)/(253/3))-1))
```

You are dividing the integer value `x - 1` by an integer value `253 / 3`.  This will truncate the value to an `int`, meaning that you'll be raising an integer power to an integer power.

To fix this, try changing this expression to

```
(((x-1)/(253.0 / 3.0))-1))
```

This now will use `double`s in the expression, giving you the value you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "This rounds downward" - no it doesn't: it's implementation-defined in C89 and truncates in C99.

Comment: @H2CO3- Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to that, integers do not give you the decimal part of numbers, so a number like 3.5 will get cut down to 3 using integer. To fix this double is the way to go. In other words 3 is different than 3.0